# How to run a PowerShell script file with Task Scheduler requiring Administrator privilege

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I setup Task Scheduler to run a PowerShell script and when I manually test the task, it doesn't do anything. I know it didn't because the script should disable the second monitor but it didn't.
However, if I launch a PowerShell window with Admin and type in the same command, it works fine.

In the Task Scheduler "General" tab, I checked "Run with highest privileges" and the user account is a local admin user.

```
Start-Transcript -Append -Path "C:\temp\transcript0.txt"
Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId "PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_1453&SUBSYS_8433103C&REV_00\3&11583659&0&19" -Confirm:$false
```

**Update:**
Added `Start-Transcript` but no log file after run is completed without errors.

Comment: Add some logging with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-7.3, maybe you can find the error then.

Comment: @Carsten.R When run with Task Scheduler, the log file is not there, but when run manually, it produces the log file.

Comment: Then you have a potential escaping issue with your task scheduler command. Some posting of this might be helpful. Cause it won't be called if there is no log. So it is no issue with you PowerShell command in general. It all about how did it called in the taskscheduler.

Comment: You could create a cmd file to circumvent potential, escaping problems with you task scheduler command. just start this cmd instead of the PowerShell exe. The initial call is still windows cmd like escaping. Cause you call powershell.exe, and if you mix powershell.exe additional parameters that can end up strange, cause you need to mix windows escaping and PowerShell escaping.